# Where is max file upload size limit set in Rails/Puma/Heroku/Paperclip/Cloudinary?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paperclip, cloudinary

I can't find the file upload size limit configuration anywhere.

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=rails+puma+max+file+upload&ia=qa

A customer states they cannot upload a 15mb file. I don't see any limits set in `config/` or the model. I'm using Puma, Heroku, Paperclip, and Cloudinary.

Rails 5.0.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the maximum file size when uploading to Cloudinary is 10MB for our Free plan and 20MB for our Plus plan. We offer more file sizes for Advanced plan onwards.

For more information: https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520592-Do-you-have-a-file-size-limit-